# more/less content toggle for large blocks of text

Tags: zepto, jquery

I'm using the following code snippet to show/hide large blocks of text within a web page.

```
/// Hide the extra content initially, using JS so that if JS is disabled, no problemo:
$('.read-more-content').addClass('hide')

// Set up a link to expand the hidden content:
.before('<a class="read-more-show" href="#">+more</a>')

// Set up a link to hide the expanded content.
.append(' <a class="read-more-hide" href="#">-less</a>');

// Set up the toggle effect:
$('.read-more-show').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).next('.read-more-content').removeClass('hide');
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('.read-more-hide').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent('.read-more-content').addClass('hide').parent().children
('.read-more-show').removeClass('hide');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

It works fine on a) small blocks of text or b) blocks of text at the end of a page.  However for long blocks of text within the page (my situation), I encounter a problem:  clicking the "more" link works fine, but scrolling down and clicking the "less link" although it hides the expanded text, does not toggle you back up to the "more link"  Instead you find yourself lower down the page.   Was wondering if there was a solution to this?  Like using an anchor toggle?  I currently have the following working on my page, but my jquery skills are pretty basic and i can't work out how to adapt the two.
//scroll to anchor text

```
$('.scrollTo').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Foundation.lib_methods.scrollTo($(window), $($(e.currentTarget).attr('href')).offset().top, 200);
});
```

The site is built in Foundation 4 so any solution needs to be compatible with zepto as well as jquery.

A link to the set up on the page is here
http://tinyurl.com/o4y42yx

any suggestions most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the core.js file replace lines 24 to 27 with the following:

```
$('.read-more-hide').on('click', function(e) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parents('.row').offset().top //scrolls up to the div with class "row" right under the +more link
        }, 800); 
  $(this).parent('.read-more-content').addClass('hide').parent().children('.read-more-show').removeClass('hide');
  return false;
});
```

I was testing it and it didn't work at first, later I tested it by disabling all the script calls in the html file (deleted the `<script src>`) and called jquery on its own in the head and it worked. You might want to check on your own what causes the conflict.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It needs more time and at the moment I don't have it to search for it and suggest a more proper solution. I hope this helps though.

Comment: Hey thanks for such a quick response - apologies for taking so long but was unexpectedly called away last week. Have tried the code you suggested. first two snippets were fine - I amended the existing js to reflect them - and checked that the id was indeed inserted on read more.  But just can't get the third snippet to work, no matter where I try to insert it into the coding, it breaks the toggle so all text visible.  Wonder if I've made a basic error? can you clarify  where in my code i should place your third snippet and whether it should replace or add to what I had before?  thanks again

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. I also commented the lines 2-5 in core.js to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ilias, I'll play around with this.  I think the problem might be with zepto not supporting scrollTop.  I'm keen to keep the built in option for zepto if I can, just not sure my coding skills are up to  it!